# ARKit and RealityKit limitation Entity number

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I am study RealityKit and I'm try to drop on the floor a set of red card divided in different row at the position tapped.

See the picture attached.
[image]

I notice that if the number of cards is to much AR kit display the cards for few second in the sene but then after a second the cards disappeared from a scene.

and on the console I get the following print out:

```
2021-10-10 15:31:31.851724+0800 indovinaWho[12166:4021700] [Session] ARSession <0x111038050>: ARSessionDelegate is retaining 14 ARFrames. This can lead to future camera frames being dropped.
```

Here my code how I drop the cards.

Basically with the following code I'm creating a AnchorEntity at location tapped and then append the entity "modCard" changing the position accordingly.

If for example I state 8 card per row in 3 row, I just see the card for few second and then suddently they disappeared from my scene.

Reality kit have a maximum number of entity can be attached to an AnchorEntity?

```
  
    
    func createCard(raycast: ARRaycastResult, maxrow: Int, cardPerRow: Int){
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(raycastResult: raycast)
        var prPosMod = simd_make_float3(0,0,0) // prev position
        let cardByside = cardPerRow/2
        DispatchQueue.global().sync {
            for _ in 1...maxrow {
                for ncard in 1...cardPerRow {
                    let modEntity = self.modelCard()
                    if ncard < cardByside {
                        modEntity.position = simd_make_float3(prPosMod.x-0.1,prPosMod.y,prPosMod.z)
                    }else {
                        modEntity.position = simd_make_float3(prPosMod.x + 0.1,prPosMod.y,prPosMod.z)
                    }
                    prPosMod = modEntity.position
                    anchor.addChild(modEntity)
                }
                prPosMod = simd_float3(0,prPosMod.y,prPosMod.z-0.1)
            }
            self.arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
        }
       
        
    }
    
    
    func modelCard() -> ModelEntity {
        let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(width: 0.08, height: 0.01, depth: 0.08, cornerRadius: 0.005, splitFaces: false)
        let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .red, isMetallic: false)
        return ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
    }
```

Comment: The ARSessionDelegate warning can probably be fixed if you create the mesh once, and apply that each time to modelCard, rather than recreating on every call

Comment: Your question states 8x3, but the image shows 6x2. you might have better luck printing out all the prPosMod values, see if those match what you'd expect

Comment: to answer your other question, there's no limit of number of child entities. If there is it's going to be a much bigger number than 24 (8*3)